# Trying to ADD numbers to a string

Tags: vb.net

I want to add some numbers to a string in this code. But I don't know how can I do it without getting the following error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "Happy Holidays!!! " to type 'Double' is not valid.' Internal Exception. FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

I don't want to SUM, I want to ADD. Here's the code:

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim Day = Now.Day
        Dim Month = Now.Month
        Dim Year = Now.Year
        Label1.Text = MonthName(Now.Month, True) //not necessary
        If Now.Month = 12 Then
            Me.Text = "Happy Holidays!!!" + " " + Day + "/" + Month + "/" + Year 'here's the problem
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot convert string to type 'Double'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20221658/cannot-convert-string-to-type-double)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the `+` operator can be used to concatenate Strings, it should not be used. The reason is because of situations like this where the compiler will attempt to treat the `+` as an addition operator instead of the String concatenation operator.

You have a couple of options:

1. Use the `&` operator
2. Use String interpolation

You can also simply call the ToString method on your DateTime object and pass in the desired format rather than getting the day, month, and year and passing them individually.

Take a look at this example:

```
Dim rightNow = DateTime.Now
Label1.Text = rightNow.ToString("MMMM")
If (rightNow.Month = 12) Then
    Me.Text = $"Happy Holidays!!! {rightNow:d/M/yyyy}"
End If
```

Comment: Support for format specifiers is built into `String.Format` and, therefore, string interpolation. That means that a better way to do that would be `Me.Text = $"Happy Holidays!!! {rightNow:d/M/yyyy)}"`.

Comment: So, if I change all + by &, will it work? EDIT: It works thank you.

Comment: @jmcilhinney good point, I've edited my code.

Comment: @AarónGarcíaEgea yes, you could do that or you could use the string interpolation example that I showed.